# Reaction of multiple diols with sulphuric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols, ethers

> [image]
>
> Find the total number of possible products

I can think of atleast three reactions that will take place in the acidic medium:

1. Pinacol-Pinacolone rearrangement
2. Intermolecular dehydration (leading to ether formation)
3. Intramolecular dehydration (epoxide formation)

Here are the possible products that would be formed:
[image]

This gives us a total of $8$ possible products.

Are any different reactions possible? Also, are any of the products that I have listed wrong? (Will any of them not be formed).

Comment: You have not got any alkenes in there. I think you might get some ethers of allylic alcohols

Comment: Dihydrobenzofurans may also be possible

Comment: Epoxides are unlikely. Unfortunately your question is too broad. Its author in textbook vastly underestimated practical aspects of such reaction.

Comment: I agree it's a poorly designed question. But anybody who voted to close as "too broad", could you please explain how *"this question currently includes multiple questions in one"*, the description which you presumably read when voting to close?